# How to open the default handler for a magnet link on java

Tags: java

TLDR; How to open a magnet link like "magnet:?xt=blablablabl" with the default application on java

---

I'm working on a application that search a website for a magnet link and opens it.
Currently I'm opening firefox passing the magnet url as a parameter, but it leaves a open tab and if firefox is not installed, this method doesn't seem to work with chrome (I didn't tested it with ie).
What I want is to open the default application that handles the magnet protocol.
I'm aware that in windows I can get that from the registry and on ubuntu i can call xdg-open, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution on java or a library that already do this. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lacking a better solution I wrote my own:
https://github.com/beothorn/URISchemeHandler 
Also added support for registering new protocol handlers.
Still wished there was a way to handle this without checking which OS is running.
Edit:
The correct name for this identifier is URI scheme, more details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme.

Comment: How can I use the library without Maven?
Any compiled jar file? Or should I compile myself?

Comment: You can download it from the repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.beothorn/URISchemeHandler . You will also need to download the other dependencies listed on the pom https://github.com/beothorn/URISchemeHandler/blob/master/pom.xml . You could make a shaded version of the library too, but you would have to use maven for it and add the shade plugin to the pom file.